# Calculating cumulative hypergeometric distribution

Tags: r, probability

Suppose I have 100 marbles, and 8 of them are red. I draw 30 marbles, and I want to know what's the probability that at least five of the marbles are red. I am currently using http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/hypergeometric.aspx and I entered 100, 8, 30, and 5 for population size, number of success, sample size, and number of success in sample, respectively. So the probability I'm interested in is Cumulative Probability: $P(X \geq 5)$ which = 0.050 in this case. My question is, how do I calculate this in R?

I tried

```
> 1-phyper(5, 8, 92, 30, lower.tail = TRUE)
[1] 0.008503108
```

But this is very different from the previous answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`phyper(5, 8, 92, 30)` gives the probability of drawing **five or fewer** red marbles.

`1 - phyper(5, 8, 92, 30)` thus returns the probability of getting **six or more** red marbles

Since you want the probability of getting **five or more** (i.e. more than 4) red marbles, you should use one of the following:

```
1 - phyper(4, 8, 92, 30)
[1] 0.05042297

phyper(4, 8, 92, 30, lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 0.05042297
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use:

```
1 - phyper(..., lower.tail = TRUE)
```

?

Easier to use:

```
phyper(..., lower.tail = FALSE)
```

.  Even if they are mathematically equivalent, there are numerical reasons for preferring the latter.

Does that fix your problem?  I believe you are putting the correct inputs into the phyper function.  Is it possible that you're looking at the wrong output in that web site you linked?